# Django Serializer Field Optional

Tags: python, django, serialization, checkbox

Right now I have an input and two checkboxes that will return a variable to python back end.
I would like to have the two checkbox with default value false and if they are checked to return true.
I think my problem is as I'm using a Serializer, that I don't get a value from the two checkboxes if they are unchecked.
If the checkbox are checked my code works and the value is saved in the model. If not I get an error

html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="var.name">
<input ng-model="var.pem" type="checkbox">
<input ng-model="var.key" type="checkbox">
```

Serializer

```
class CreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = (  
                    'name',
                    'pem',
                    'key',
                 )
```

model

```
class Thing(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        pem = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        key = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Would it be possible to have an existing value for the Serializer if the checkbox stay unchecked?

Comment: Please show how the view which is saving the data.

Comment: I added the part for saving into my model

Comment: What is the error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

When you don't pass anything in the checkbox, there is no value in the `validated_data` dict, which basically assigns `pem` and `key` key as `None` in the dict.
The fields you've describes in the model does not support a `null` value, since it is a `BooleanField`.

**Solution**:

```
name = thing_ser.validated_data.get('name')
# add default values if the key is not present.
pem = thing_ser.validated_data.get('pem', False)
keystore = thing_ser.validated_data.get('keystore', False)

# if it was present and it was None.
if pem is None:
    pem = False
if keystore is None:
    keystore = False

# save into model
thing1=Thing(name=name, pem=pem, keystore=keystore)
thing1.save()
```

This solution changes two things, it adds a default value as `False` when the `validated_data` does not have `pem` and `keystore` keys present in it. Moreover, the main part is to check whether they are `None` or not, if it is, make it `False`.